# Can a magento 2 question be a duplicate of a magento 1 question?

Tags: discussion

This question got my eye [How does getChildHtml() work and what does it do in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117642/how-getchildhtml-function-works-and-what-does-it-do-in-magento-2)

1. Is this question is wrong Tag Added?
2. Can a question be a duplicate with magento 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

> Can a [Magento 2] question be a duplicate with magento 1?

Yes.

But not this one.

---

In this particular example, I believe that the question is *not* a duplicate of the Magento 1 example, because the specific hierarchy and explanation for Magento 1 actually has little relevance to Magento 2 other than conceptually, because the platform has changed so much.

Yes - there are guaranteed to be some questions that have been answered for Magento 1 that Magento 2 equivalents can be closed as a duplicate of, for example something like *"How to I change configuration value XYZ?"*, but this question in particular deserves a Magento 2 answer since the Magento 1 answer will:

- Leave people confused when the file paths aren't the same
- As above when the class hierarchy and names aren't the same
- As above when subtle differences are introduced in Magento 2 and not Magento 1, but not covered by the answer (because it's not a Magento 2 answer!)

Answer (score 5):

Well I guess it a case by case situation.

I am the one who marked that question as duplicate **because that method does exactly the same thing on Magento 2 and Magento 1**, I don't see the point of answering the M2 question whereas the M1 question already has a good answer.

On top of that if you check the method, they are almost the same except the M2 version has been refactored a bit to match the new system.

However, I reckon **maybe we should update the original M1 question and answer so it is clear that they apply for both M1 and M2**.

Comment: ,how much time ,you have spent at MSE.I wonder at your activity :)

Comment: @AmitBera Raphael Is same like you, helping 24 * 7 for others.